# Invalid attribute value syntax for android:largescreens: = "true"

Tags: android

I am developing an android application with minSdkVersion of 11 and targetSdkVersion of 17.
I am designing this apps for multiple screen sizes. So i put the support for all the screens in manifest file.I want this apps to support all density.

My Manifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <supports-screens
                android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens= "true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="CommApp" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.sample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity android:name="HomePage"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
               android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

          <activity android:name="Registering"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              ></activity>

         <activity android:name="ListviewActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have created layout folder for all screen sizes as res/layout-small, res/layout-normal, res/layout-large, res/layout-xlarge.
I want to run this application in a emulator of screen size 720x1280, for this device I created all layout files in res/layout-xlarge folder. 
But while running it shows the following error:

```
Invalid attribute value syntax for android:largescreens: = "true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"/
```

I do not know what is the wrong? Can anyone please tell me the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is complaining about the space following the `=` symbol in the `android:largeScreens` attribute. Try removing the extra space.

Comment: There is no effect of space after `=`. It will not give error even if you have space(s)

Comment: If I run this on device with screen size of 720x1280 the layout files in "layout-normal" only getting loaded,But I have a separate folder "layout-xlarge" for this screen size.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with my attributes formatted like this:

```
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens            = "false"
                    android:normalScreens           = "false"
                    android:largeScreens            = "false"
                    android:xlargeScreens           = "true"
                    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp = "720" />
```

The error:

```
update-manifest:
     [exec] Invalid attribute name: android:smallscreens
```

Removing the whitespace around the equals sign fixed it.