# how to design an apps for screen size of 720x1280

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android application with minSdkVersion of 11 and targetSdkVersion of 17.
I am designing this apps for multiple screen sizes. So i put the support for all the screens in manifest file.I want this apps to support all density.

My Manifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <supports-screens
                android:smallScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens= "true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="CommApp" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

          <activity android:name="First"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              ></activity>

         <activity android:name="Second"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            ></activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have created layout folder for all screen sizes as res/layout-small, res/layout-normal, res/layout-large, res/layout-xlarge.
I want to run this application in a emulator of screen size 720x1280, for this device I created all layout files in res/layout-xlarge folder. 
But while running it shows the following error:

```
Invalid attribute value syntax for android:largescreens: = "true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"/
```

I do not know what is the wrong? Can anyone please tell me the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact copy of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207526/invalid-attribute-value-syntax-for-androidlargescreens-true) question

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:largeScreens= "true"
```

to

```
android:largeScreens="true"
```

There should be no spacing in between the equal sign.

Comment: There is no effect of space after `=`, both will work